# Method App\Http\Controllers\loginController::create does not exist

Tags: laravel

O erro está aparecendo quando tento abrir no navegador a 2º rota, se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito agradecido!

Segue print do erro:

https://prnt.sc/IK6WRaFn6YKU

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class loginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {

# Retorna o arquivo index dentro da pasta HTML
        return view('HTML.index');
    }

    public function user()
    {
# Retorna o arquivo user dentro da pasta HTML
        return view('HTML.user');
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\loginController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/teste_pratico', [loginController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/teste_pratico/cadastro_usuarios', [loginController::class, 'create']);
Route::get('/teste_pratico/cadastro_produtos', [loginController::class, 'create']);
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

o erro acontece por literalmente não existir um método chamado create no controller chamado.

Note que ao chamar o método index a página é exibida corretamente, já que o método index existe:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    return view('HTML.index');
}
```

Apenas crie o método no controller da mesma forma que criou index:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    // retorno da função aqui
}
```